# Checkio long repeat challenge

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the challenge you are asked to find the length of the longest substring that consists of the same letter. For example, line "aaabbcaaaa" contains four substrings with the same letters "aaa", "bb","c" and "aaaa". The last substring is the longest one which makes it an answer. Input: String. Output: Int. Example:

> long_repeat('sdsffffse') == 4
>
> long_repeat('ddvvrwwwrggg') == 3

Here is my code :

```
def long_repeat(text):
    text = list(text)
    counter = []
    c = []

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[0] == text[1]:
            c.append(text.pop(0))
        else:
            counter.append(c)
            c = []
    print text # should be empty 
    print counter # should contain a lists of the repeated letters
```

Output:

```
>>>long_repeat('aaabbccc')
['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
[['a', 'a'], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

why the loop stopes when it finishes the first letter which is 'a' in this case?

Comment: I'm confused how this is even working. You should get an error along the lines of `'str' object has no attribute 'pop'`.

Comment: I turned the text into a list in the second line

Comment: You did, but `pop` is called on `text`, not on `txt`.

Comment: Mistyped it :)!

Comment: `pop`ing from a list while iterating over it is a very bad idea.

Comment: Why? I mean it worked just as expected in the first letter

Comment: @belle: iteration uses an index; so you first looked at element 0, then 1, then 2. Popping from the start moves everything up one step to the left; so what was at index 1 is now at index 0, but the *iteration indices don't adjust*. So if you just handled element 1, you next look at index 2 but that was the element at index 3 before the pop, and the one at index 2 is no longer there but at index 1..

Answer (score 0):

When `test[0] != text[1]` e.g when input is at "ab" you aren't appending the a to the c variable

In addition, Python string has no "pop" method hence why it's exiting out (pay close attention to error returned).

Use something like this for pop

```
c.append(text[-1]) 
text = text[:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you i have noticed that one letter in each loop will be missed, i was planning on dealing with it later. I will take your good luck, need some :)

Answer (score 0):

The loop does not stop. Your `else` statement does not move the list forward (no `pop` here). By the way, your logic is not quite correct. And also, it is not a good idea to pop the character and then collect it each turn. You can use integers to record all necessary information you need, including position, current count, maximum count and etc.